# JPA Hibernate: Post and Get using a foreign key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I am using Spring, but also Hibernate to set up a RESTful service. Unfortunately, I don't know how to work on the weak entity's table when I just have the related foreign key.

I think, it is difficult to explain, let me give you an example:

Imagine we have the class Person and the class Dog. Every Dog that exists has exactly one Person as owner. A Person don't have to own a Dog. However, a Person can have as many Dogs as he or she wants.

Unfortunately, I am not able to show you any code because ctrl+k, or code tags doesn't work, but there are layers for both, Person and Dog:

in Package com.example.person:
Person,
PersonController,
PersonService,
PersonRepository

in Package com.example.dog:
Dog,
DogController,
DogService,
DogRepository

Now, I am in DogService.java. I want to do two things:

1. Get all dogs of a Person just having the Person's id:
   My first idea was to use the Query annotation in DogRepository to do something like "... WHERE d.person = ?1". But I don't know exactly how to do that.
2. Post a dog by using the id of the Person:
   How can I save something to the Repository by using the Person's id? Ususally I would use dogRepository. save(...).

It is like an invisible wall between dog and person in my head. Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: person will have an id property - so if you want all dogs with an owner with a certain id, you might use "select dog from Dog dog where dog.owner.id = :personId". For POST, you'll need to accept the Person ID and look up the person associated to it, and use that reference to set as the dog's owner. dogRepository.save might take in a dog instance and a String owner id - in REST it might be a dog JSON body instance with an owner ID string as a query or path parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped a lot. I tried this for POST: got Person using a JPA query, and my respone entity answers the right JSON. But when I want to get all dogs using dogRepository.findAll() (it is an org.springframework.stereotype.Repository) a long error message (Internal Error). Here part of it (it is too long):

Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor